# How to ensure that timestamp is UTC time at any machine

Tags: erlang, elixir

```
> os:system_time(seconds).
1470361698
```

This is correct UTC timestamp, but I'm not sure if it is not system-related value. Is it?

How then I can ensure that same program ran on different machine will still operate in UTC timezone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os:system_time` returns the "OS System Time" which is defined to be approximately the "POSIX Time", the number of seconds since Epoch, which is defined to be 00:00:00 UTC, 1970-01-01, so it should always return the "UTC Timestamp". Erlang has excellent documentation about [Time Correction](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/time_correction.html), have a look at the [OS System Time](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/time_correction.html#OS_System_Time) and [POSIX Time](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/time_correction.html#POSIX_Time) sections.

> ## OS System Time
>
> The operating systems view of POSIX time. To retrieve it, call `os:system_time()`. This may or may not be an accurate view of POSIX time. This time may typically be adjusted both backwards and forwards without limitation. That is, time warps may be observed.
>
> ## POSIX Time
>
> Time since Epoch. Epoch is defined to be 00:00:00 UTC, 1970-01-01. A day in POSIX time is defined to be exactly 86400 seconds long. Strangely enough Epoch is defined to be a time in UTC, and UTC has another definition of how long a day is. Quoting the Open Group "POSIX time is therefore not necessarily UTC, despite its appearance". The effect of this is that when an UTC leap second is inserted, POSIX time either stops for a second, or repeats the last second. If an UTC leap second would be deleted (which has not happened yet), POSIX time would make a one second leap forward.